# Can Collections.sort() take treeSet as first argument? If not why?

Tags: java, list, collections, set, comparator

I have my 'Person' `class` as follows -

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int marks;
    private String name;

    Person(int marks, String name) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person: Marks = " + marks + ", Name =  " + name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return marks > person.marks ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Now in `main method` I have created another `comparator` with opposite `sorting` -

```
Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
                int marks1 = p1.getMarks();
                int marks2 = p2.getMarks();
                return marks1 > marks2 ? -1 : 1;
            }
        };
```

Now, I create a `TreeSet` -

```
TreeSet<Person> treeSet1 = new TreeSet<>(List.of(
                new Person(67, "Himani"),
                new Person(73, "Hasani"),
                new Person(21, "Rohini")
        ));
```

Now, I try passing treeSet as an argument to `Collections.sort()` -

```
Collections.sort(treeSet1, comparator);
```

Here, I get the following error -

```
Required type                         Provided

list:List<T>                         TreeSet<Person>
                              
c:Comparator<? super T>              Comparator<Person>
```

As far as I can deduce from the error - `Collections.sort()` with `comparator` can only be used on `List` and not `Set`.

Am I correct? If not where am I going wrong? If yes why am I correct?

Comment: Sets are inherently unordered collections of things, so they cannot be sorted

Comment: But I can set my own rules using Comparable, only Comparator gives me trouble

Comment: It's not the comparator that is giving you trouble, if you look at Collections.sort it requires a List. TreeSet is not a list, and therefore can't be used there no matter what comparator you're going to use. This is because, in order for the generic sort implementation to work, it requires functions from the List interface to place things in the proper order. The Set interface has no such methods, because it's not meant to be ordered.

Comment: Well, to be precise, the comparator *is* giving you trouble, but independently of the `sort` method. A comparator is supposed to return zero when both argument are equal, so a comparator that never returns zero can’t be correct. The same applies to your broken `compareTo` method. Did you notice that the `TreeSet`’s `contains` method always returns `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `Collections.sort` is of type `List<T>`.  So you can only pass `List` objects to it, not `Set` objects, or anything else.

This is sensible.  The reason is that `Set` objects are of two types.

- There are those that are, by their nature, always unsorted, such as `HashSet`.  It doesn't make sense to sort these.
- There are those that are, by their nature, always sorted the same way, such as `TreeSet`.  It doesn't make sense to sort these, because they're already sorted.

I think maybe what you want is to take your `TreeSet` and have it sorted using a different `Comparator`.  To do that, you'll have to make a new `TreeSet` with your new `Comparator`, and copy the entries across from the old set using `addAll`.

Comment: You mean a new set first using `TreeSet(Comparator comparator)` constructor and then `treeSet_previous.clone()`?

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Ok, but please explain, why my method won't work? (`clone()` instead of `addAll()`)

Comment: `.clone()` literally __clones__. Comparator and all. You want: `TreeSet<String> newSet = new TreeSet<String>(someNewComparator); newSet.addAll(oldSet);`.